# simple css trick - is it possible?

Tags: html, css

i am wondering whether this is possible: i have an `id` defined in css in this form.

```
#close{
  font-size:11px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#close:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but here i have to repeat the definition of this id just to add `hover` event. is there any possibility to do something like this?

```
#close{
  font-size:11px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}:hover{cursor: pointer;}
```

this would save some extra typing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this in CSS, however you may find CSS preprocessers like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) interesting. They allow you to next selectors, see this example in SASS:

```
.some-div {
    #close {
        font-size:11px;
        text-decoration: underline;

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.some-div #close {
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.some-div #close:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Note that these aren't supported by browsers, you get programs to compile them which outputs CSS to include in your webpage.

Comment: css with this kind of property would be great! but SASS is a bit tedious to import into page..

Comment: @doniyor There is no alternative in this case. I'd recommend using a file system monitor to automatically convert your .scss files to .css (check out LiveReload: http://livereload.com/ ), or using a plugin for your IDE that compiles at save. There are many available for Visual Studio.

Comment: I use Mindscape WebWorkbench for Visual Studio and it works great. Makes writing CSS so enjoyable :) look for plugins for your IDE, I believe there are a bunch.

Comment: @JosephLennox I'm not sure what benefits LiveReload gives but SASS was built on ruby and comes with the monitor functionality describe.

Answer (score 2):

well, in this particular case you could just have

```
#close{
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As the pointer only displays when you're hovering anyway ;)

Otherwise i don't believe there are any syntax tricks, but you could use a precompiler like SASS

Comment: yeah, i can do so, but my case is just a sample case, what if you want more things on ``hover``.. i hope, people are working on this. :(

Comment: i feel your pain. SASS is good if you have large scale projects - but often i have small projects that don't warrant it and it would be nice to have a syntax like the one you mentioned ^

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is working on this in W3C CSS Working Group as far as I can tell (*)

There're:

- preprocessors, (see other answers),
- there is copy-pasting,
- maybe a CSS ZenCoding/Emmett plugin (never heard of it though and it's not needed as badly as Emmett is for HTML),
- maybe a macro like "*go copy the last line of my CSS file with a `{` at its end and the previous lines if they end with a comma*"
- AND there are methodologies like [OOCSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/), [BEM](http://bem.info/method/), etc that will keep the need of nesting selectors down to 1 or 2 levels, that is only the pseudos and from time to time a second class (barely no id, just classes are used)

(*) It's barely needed in the browser imo. DRY things in CSS I can think of are classes, [:matches() (previously known as :-vendor-any() )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aany) and inherit, initial values, "variables" and a new [all](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand) property (all these things are only related by the fact they avoid longer tasks, it's quite unrelated to your question ;) )